# How to make instances twist about a curve

Tags: geometry-nodes, vector

I am wanting this ring to appear as a twisted chain, hopefully with a variable number of 180 turns it makes as an integer input to the Geometry Nodes group. I want the chain to be twisted as a whole. I.e. if you were to cut the loop and suspend the chain so it hung from an end, it would untwist, like a twisted rope swing.

This is the ring I have with the geometry notes. **This is currently incorrect:**

[image: ring proto]

These are the nodes I have:

[image: nodes proto]

How best to make instances twist about a curve in Geometry Nodes?

Edit: Here is a demo of what I'd like to achieve. Apologies that the rings are intersecting each other. This is not desired: They are meant to realistically link together.

[image: demo still]

Note that I would like to be able to adjust the starting angle, to achieve a rolling effect, like this:

[image: demo animated]

Comment: can u pls show a picture how it should look like?

Comment: do you mean like this? [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/npoGM.png

Comment: @Chris I have added a demo of what I would like it to look like.

Comment: last try....do you want this? [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y70SJ.gif

Comment: @Chris Not quite. You got the rolling effect, but I also want the chain to be twisted as a whole. I.e., if you were to cut this loop and let the chain hang straight from an end, it would untwist.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

[image]

Each link's points are rotated about its local Y by a function of its local X, before being instanced on a circle, and then converted to a mesh.

[image]

... which can be animated by key-framing the tilt angle of the *Set Tilt* node in the Main Ring cluster:

[image]

You can introduce an initial twist to the chain, of, say, `pi` * the main ring's (0-1) Spline Parameter, and animate a delta: an additional angle to that....

[image]

.. with this sort of 'rolling' result:

[image]

Comment: Not quite, but thank you for pointing out the curve to points node as a source of some orientation. I bet that’ll help in the final solution.

Comment: You’ve got the roll, but I also want the chain to be twisted as a whole. I.e. if you were to cut it and hang it vertically, it would untwist like a twisted rope swing. I have clarified in the original question.

Comment: @TheLabCat 3rd time lucky? :)

Comment: YES! PTL that’s it.